# Javascript: use string as object key

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

If I have:

```js
var myKey = "This_is_my_key"
var myObj = {"This_is_my_key" : true}
```

How do I access `myObj` at `myKey`?

Comment: `myObj[myKey] = myValue;`

Comment: var myObj=JSON.parse('{"'+myKey+'":'+myValue+'}');

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try this

```
var myKey = "This_is_my_key";
var myValue = true;

myObj[myKey] = myValue;
```

This is same as

```
myObj.This_is_my_key=true
```